# Test-Path IIS:\SslBinding using wildcard dns name throws illegal characters error

Tags: powershell, iis, wildcard, windows-10, web-administration

IIS10 on Windows 10 supports SSL bindings to wildcard host headers e.g. `*.example.com`.

Creating a new **SSL binding** for a wildcard host header works fine, however, when the binding exists, `Test-Path` fails, throwing an `InvalidArgument` "Illegal characters in path" e.g. `Test-Path IIS:\SslBindings\!443!*.example.com`

I've tried using `-LiteralPath` as well as `-Path` but both give the same error - *but only when the binding exists*. Testing a non-existent path returns `$false` as you would expect.

Am I missing something? Or is this a bug in Test-Path/WebAdministration?

**example.ps1** (windows 10 only):

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

# test binding, create if missing
# fails on wildcard test when the binding exists
if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath IIS:\SslBindings\*!443!*.example.com))
{ 
    Push-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\My

    # find or create a certificate
    $targetCert = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? { ($_.NotAfter -gt (Get-Date)) -and ($_.DnsNameList -contains "*.example.com") } | Sort NotAfter -Descending | select -First 1
    if ($targetCert -eq $null)
    {
        $targetCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "*.example.com" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
    }

    # bind to host header *
    $targetCert | New-Item -Path IIS:\SslBindings\*!443!*.example.com -SSLFlags 1

    Pop-Location
}
```

The **work-around** I'm currently using is:

```
if (-not (Get-ChildItem IIS:\SslBindings | ?{ $_.host -eq "*.example.com" -and $_.port -eq 443 }))
{
  ...
}
```

**Update**

Worth noting is that `Get-ChildItem IIS:\SslBindings\*!443!*.example.com` works without an issue.

Comment: I doubt it is the issue but you should be quoting that as a good practice `Test-Path -LiteralPath "IIS:\SslBindings\*!443!*.example.com"`

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I did have a go with both options. I'd normally use a variables here too. Worth noting is that `Get-ChildItem IIS:\SslBindings\*!443!*.example.com` works without an issue, and the powershell console happily tab-completes the path when it exists as well.

Comment: @DaveTransom I'm not usually one to jump to this conclusion but it sounds like a bug. Probably best to report it on Microsoft Connect. And definitely don't put too much stock into tab completion. AFAIK it still doesn't tab complete `[ValidateSet()]` items with spaces correctly, so it's not exactly to most trustworthy measure.